# Exclude CMS page from full page cache

Tags: magento

I have a CMS page that loads a template. This template is a single line of php code that sends the POST data to a helper.  Depending on a certain part of that POST data, the helper will do one of two things.

My problem:  Magento caches the outcome of that helper, and will use that outcome for every subsequent time.

Is there a way to exclude a CMS page from the full page cache?  I've seen some write-ups on how to exclude blocks through hole punching,  but I'm not using a block. I just have a single CMS page that loads a template.

Comment: Which Magento version do you use?

Comment: The latest EE version.